# Rails has_many association returning empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

We have a legacy app running on Rails `4.0.12` and I'm wondering if this is some weird `ActiveRecord` bug that has since been resolved.

Here's my model:

```
class Gathering < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gathering_contents, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the association returns an empty array until reloaded. Example console output:

```
g = Gathering.last    
g.gathering_contents
GatheringContent Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "gathering_contents".* FROM "gathering_contents" WHERE "gathering_contents"."gathering_id" = 'f6b6a7a7-7f51-4c56-af95-42567f7bc15b'  [["gathering_id", "f6b6a7a7-7f51-4c56-af95-42567f7bc15b"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Running the raw SQL query returns two results. Reloading the association returns two results as well:

```
g.gathering_contents.reload
GatheringContent Load (4.7ms)  SELECT "gathering_contents".* FROM "gathering_contents" WHERE "gathering_contents"."gathering_id" = 'f6b6a7a7-7f51-4c56-af95-42567f7bc15b'  [["gathering_id", "f6b6a7a7-7f51-4c56-af95-42567f7bc15b"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<GatheringContent id: "5e82a73c-036b-4ff1-9af3-2b19c2f1746b", gathering_id: "f6b6a7a7-7f51-4c56-af95-42567f7bc15b", course_id: "ad3eb286-3617-46bd-a10d-6d09cca23b64", path_id: nil, created_at: "2016-03-30 12:52:35", updated_at: "2016-03-30 12:52:35", public_course_id: nil, company_course_id: "ad3eb286-3617-46bd-a10d-6d09cca23b64", user_id: "33626432-0fa0-439f-9920-9f62ff26ffc6", admin_id: nil, conversation_id: nil>, #<GatheringContent id: "3ef08d57-d294-48a2-a46d-eab4b1a43132", gathering_id: "f6b6a7a7-7f51-4c56-af95-42567f7bc15b", course_id: nil, path_id: nil, created_at: "2016-04-01 15:19:27", updated_at: "2016-04-01 15:19:27", public_course_id: nil, company_course_id: nil, user_id: "458fa79f-4d1f-450b-bf4a-091b1183f86c", admin_id: nil, conversation_id: "8dbe18e7-a78d-45ca-9e3b-8fa403675f0b">]>
```

I don't have a good theory for why the query returns an empty result until reloaded. Thank you for any inputs!

Comment: What happens when you run `g.gathering_contents.all` or `g.gathering_contents.first` instead?

Comment: It seems like Rails is returning the association cache when you call `g.gathering_contents`. Reloading it clears the cache and hits the database again.

Comment: Calling `g.gathering_contents.to_a` returns `[]`, `#first` returns `nil`. @MarkMerritt indeed, the association being cached is my only  working hypothesis. However, where's the cache coming from if I just started a fresh console process via `rails c`?

Comment: what happens if you open a new console and run `Rails.cache.clear`, then try to grab the association? I believe the cache is maintained...

Comment: Good idea. We're using `memcached` to persist the cache. I tried clearing it but still seeing an empty array returned.